# gnome-terminal 2 separate icons in taskbar

Tags: kubuntu, kde, gnome-terminal

I have pinned the desktop application I've created for running gnome-terminal to my taskbar. However, when I click and a terminal window opens up it opens with a separate icon, as can be seen in the picture below. If I open multiple terminal windows they all get grouped into that second icon.

[image]

I've tried pinning the second icon to the taskbar, but it does nothing when clicked.

I've also done some googling and found lots of old threads saying that gnome-terminal can be launched with the option "--disable-factory", but that options seems to have been removed in a previous version of gnome-terminal.

Is there any way to fix this issue without downgrading to a previous version of gnome-terminal?

Thanks!

Edit: The desktop application just runs the command `gnome-terminal`

Edit 2: I'm running Kubuntu 19.04.

Edit 3: I think the issue is that the `gnome-terminal` command starts a `gnome-terminal-server` process, so the left icon is my pinned desktop app while the right icon are instances of `gnome-terminal-server`.

Comment: You will need to provide info on "the desktop application you've created", or at least tell how you are calling gnome-terminal.

Comment: @vanadium, the desktop application just runs the command "gnome-terminal"

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @Kulfy I'm using Kubuntu 19.04

Comment: Kubuntu uses Konsole as its default terminal. Is it Konsole or have you installed GNOME terminal explicitly?

Comment: @Kulfy, I've installed GNOME terminal explicitly

Comment: So this is an issue specific to KDE: I see you included the info now, will add a tag to reflect this.